# python imap gmail parser error: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_string'

Tags: python, parsing, gmail, imap

can anyone help with this parser

```
import getpass, imaplib, email

def split_addrs(s):

    if not(s): return []
    outQ = True
    cut = -1
    res = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i]=='"': outQ = not(outQ)
        if outQ and s[i]==',':
            res.append(email.utils.parseaddr(s[cut+1:i]))
            cut=i
    res.append(email.utils.parseaddr(s[cut+1:i+1]))
    return res

def get_addresses( name, password):

    mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login( name , password )
    print "In email account, accessing \"%s\" All mail...\n"
    mail.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"')
    result,data=mail.search(None,"ALL")
    ids=data[0].split()[-10:]
    print "Processing %d emails...\n" % ( len(ids) )
    msgs = mail.fetch(','.join(ids),'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')[1][0::2]
    addr=[]
    print msgs
    for x,msg in msgs:
        msgobj = email.message_from_string(msg)
        addr.extend(split_addrs(msgobj['to']))
        addr.extend(split_addrs(msgobj['from']))
        addr.extend(split_addrs(msgobj['cc']))

    mail.close()
    mail.logout()
    addr_set = set(addr)
    print "Fetched and writing %d unique name and emails to scraped_email.txt...\n" % ( len(addr_set) )
    f = open('scraped_emails.txt', 'w')
    for each in addr_set:
        name, address = each 
        print "%s, %s" % (name, address)
        f.write("%s, %s\n" % (name, address))
    f.close()
    print "Done"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    email_address = raw_input('Enter your email: ')
    print "Username: %s" % ( email_address )
    get_addresses( email_address, getpass.getpass())
```

this is my output

```
In email account, accessing "%s" All mail...
```

Processing 10 emails...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richard/environments/google-tools/gmail-addresses/program.py", line 52, in <module>
    get_addresses( email_address, getpass.getpass())
  File "/home/richard/environments/google-tools/gmail-addresses/program.py", line 30, in get_addresses
    msgobj = email.message_from_string(msg)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_string'
```

i plan on making the folder selectable later but for now wanted to try and get it working on all mail.

can anyone spot my error

i'm using python 2.7 with eclipse pydev ide

thanks

Answer (score 0):

all worked fine in python 3 so no need for help